# How can I web scrape for website contacts?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, hyperlink

I want to make a program which could search from notepad list for websites that have their contacts  mentioned in main web page. Also so it could open that Hyperlink and print Innertext of contacts to console. I am using C# and so far tried this:

```
public static void SearchContacts(string address)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string reply = client.DownloadString(address);

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    doc.LoadHtml(reply);
    HtmlNode[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul").ToArray();

    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes) {
      if (node.InnerHtml.Contains("contacts")) {
          // Open hyperlink and copy contact InnerText
      else { 
          Console.WriteLine(address + " Website contacts are not found"); 
      }
}
```

I am new to net scraping and appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: And what is the problem/error you are experiencing?

Comment: // Open hyperlink and copy contact InnerText                                                                 
I don't know how to copy hyperlink and print it out to console

Comment: It is impossible for us to know the structure of the html you are obtaining. You could do some research on AngleSharp or HtmlAgility pack. There should be many examples to guide you.

Comment: It's multiple websites that I am web scraping, so structures are always going to be bit different, here is example of one : <a href="https://pigu.lt/lt/t/kontaktai">Kontaktai</a>